# How to allow both resource server and client login for an endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to set up security filter chains in a way that both client (session-based user login) and resource_server (key/secret) authentication allow access to a subset of my paths. This is Spring Security 6.

Let's say I want "/actuator/**" to be accessible for either resource_server or client.

What I tried was

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain authorizeInternal(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
  http.oauth2ResourceServer(withDefaults());

  http.authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req

    // resource server
    .requestMatchers("/actuator/**")
    .hasAuthority("SCOPE_read_actuator")

    // logged in user
    .requestMatchers("/actuator/**")
    .hasRole("developer")
  );
}
```

This will prevent both methods from access, which I understand but don't see an alternative.

I also tried around with multiple `SecurityFilterChain`s but ended up with pretty much the same problem.

I'm also thinking I could use `.access("/actuator/**", authManager)`, but it looks like I'd need to implement something like an `OrAuthenticationManager` that checks both my managers' decision.

Am I overlooking an easier way?

Comment: Your example seems to suggest you have other endpoints (not shown) that you are trying to protect differently, is that correct? Otherwise, you should just have `http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())`. Perhaps you may be confusing authentication with authorization?

Comment: It's very possible I'm confusing things, it's pretty much trial and error on my side  Yes I have other endpoints, but only with those `hasRole` and `hasAuthority` on their own, and it's working as expected except for this "either" scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to protect a particular URL (or set of URLs) with an "or" rule, you can use `AuthorizationManagers.anyOf`.

```java
import static org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority;
import static org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasRole;
import static org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorizationManagers.anyOf;
...

http
    // ...
    .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").access(anyOf(
            hasAuthority("SCOPE_read_actuator"),
            hasRole("developer")
        ))
        // ...
    );
```

See the [Authorize HTTP Requests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html) page in the docs for more info.